# AWS Lambda Rerouting after Twitter Authorizing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twitter, serverless-framework, twitter-oauth

I implemented a twitter login authorizer and I put an API route as the callback.

The Lambda function evoked on that route is the following:

```
const loginTwitterCallback = async (e, context) => {
  const fetch = (...args) =>
    import("node-fetch").then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

  const state = e.queryStringParameters.state;
  const code = e.queryStringParameters.code;

  try {
    await fetch(
      "https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token?code=" +
        code +
        "&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" +
        process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID +
        "&code_verifier=jwqoijoiw&redirect_uri=" + MY REDIRECT URI,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(async (data) => {
        const accessToken = data.access_token;
        return {
          headers: {
            Location:
              "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/social?type=twitter&access_token=" +
              encodeURIComponent(accessToken),
          },
          body: null,
          statusCode: 302,
        };
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Basically the user should be re-routed to the front-end where another POST request will be made to the API which will make a request to the Twitter API with the Bearer token and update the database.

The point is, I'm not being redirected to the front-end in the first place and I don't understand how to fix it.

Thanks a lot in advance.